# Configure apache web server on Ubuntu to do directory listing of all directories by default

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration, webserver

How to configure apache web server on Ubuntu to do directory listing of all directories by default ?

I added this entry

```
<Directory /var/lib/jenkins>
        Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

in my

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

But listing still does not work. How do I enable `mod_autoindex` module ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific file created to load modules you can add the following line to that file:

```
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

You can see if you have another configuration file by viewing the httpd.conf or I guess in your case apache2.conf for a line that will say:

```
Include /insert/path/to/modules/config/file
```

If apache2.conf is where it's loading the modules, simply add the very first code block line I put in the answer.

Feel free to check out the documentation to see what customization you are able to do once you have mod_autoindex working via https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html

If you want to get "fancy" with your indexes check out the FancyIndexing option - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions.fancyindexing